# Why do I get "undefined is not an object(evaluating "inputRef.current.incFont"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

It doesnt do what I want.

I have two **textArea**, I use them as they were button. One will increase FontSize, other will decrease it.

When I click on *decreaseFont* text, i get that error.

Here is the code I added,

```
const MyInput = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {

  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(12);

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref,() => {
    incFont: () => {setFontSize(fontSize+2)}
    decFont: () => {setFontSize(fontSize-2)}
  })
  

  return(
    <TextInput style={{fontSize, borderColor:"red",borderWidth:1}} />
  )


})
```

inside my main function:

```
 const inputRef = useRef();
<View>
 <MyInput ref={inputRef}/>
          <Text onPress={()=>inputRef.current.incFont()}>IncreaseFont</Text>
          <Text onPress={() => inputRef.current.decFont()}>DecreaseFont</Text>

        </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `useImperativeHandle` like below,

```
React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    incFont: () => {
      setFontSize(fontSize + 2);
    },
    decFont: () => {
      setFontSize(fontSize - 2);
    }
  }));
```

working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-burnell-0h70g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you, it works. But can I ask why whenever I click on "decreaseFont or increaseFont" text, it clears the textInput.  I mean if i write "hey" in TextInput, and click on increaseFont, i want to see it bigger, but it clears the text, and then it increases. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Btw I did what you did on my android emulator. It works on codesandbox as expected, but on emulator it does the same, i mean it still clears the text when i click on decrease or increase. Maybe i have something wrong in my other codes.

Comment: I still didnt understand how it can work on codesandbox, but not on my environment..